# convert a Mat to byte array in JNI c++

Tags: java, c++, opencv, java-native-interface

How can I convert a `cv::Mat` data to `jbyteArray` in C++ and return it as an object in Java?

```
std::vector <BYTE> v_char ( src.rows * src.cols );
memcpy(v_char.data(), src.data, v_char.size() * sizeof(BYTE));
jbyteArray result = env->NewByteArray( v_char.size() * sizeof(BYTE));
jobject jEmuResponse = env->NewObject ( emu_response,emu_response_constructor, result, number );

return jEmuResponse;
```

I tried the above code which is not working. Please point me where I went wrong.

Comment: You never copy the data into the result jbyteArray.

Comment: As of OpenCV 2.4.5, a [Java binding](http://opencv.org/opencv-java-api.html) is supported.